# calculating averages and creating a column

Tags: r

I have  two columns (Group and weight) and I want to calculate  the average groups and then minus each cell with this average. I want to  have a function in R , but I struggle to create it. Please can you help. Many thanks

```
Group   weight  Diff
A       10     -2
A       14      2
B      12      -1
B      14       1
C      14       1
C      12      -1
D      12     -0.5
D      13      0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `ave`.

```
> d <- data.frame(Group=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2),
+                 weight=c(10,14,12,14,14,12,12,13))
> d$Diff <- d$weight - ave(d$weight, d$Group)
> d
  Group weight Diff
1     A     10 -2.0
2     A     14  2.0
3     B     12 -1.0
4     B     14  1.0
5     C     14  1.0
6     C     12 -1.0
7     D     12 -0.5
8     D     13  0.5
```

Comment: Thank Aron, If I have more  than one Group, can you help me how to create  diff

Comment: Ha, I was looking for the `FUN` part in `ave` just to finally recall that `ave` was originally writtne in order to calculate means :)

Comment: @user3546966 you can pass as many grouping variables as you wish into `ave`. Though I would do it in the same environment in order to avoid `$` calls, such as `transform(d, Diff = ave(weight, Group1, Group2))`, for example.

Comment: Could you  give an example please- David

Comment: I just did... Didn't you see the `transform` example? I assumed you have two frouping variables. You can extrapolate to more.

Comment: nice use of transform, David!

Comment: David Thanks- I meant create a hypothetical matrix with codes

Comment: @user3546966: This should be more than enough to go on.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `library(data.table)`:

```
d <- data.table(Group=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2), weight=c(10,14,12,14,14,12,12,13))
d[,Diff:=weight-mean(weight),by=Group]
```

Comment: How did you come up with `mean(.SD$weight)`? Why didn't you do the same for `weight` too then (as in `.SD$weight`)? The whole point of `data.table` NSE is that it's evaluates it's variables within it's environment without the need in `$`. All you need to do is `d[, Diff := weight - mean(weight), Group]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't know that you could do that and I'm surprised that it works. you're treating `weight` as a value in one instance and a vector in the other. that seems odd to me. `.SD` returns a data table, so I could have useed `.SD[,weight]` instead of `.SD$weight`. but thank you for pointing that out, answer updated

Comment: `wieght` is treated as a vector in both instances  so not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: `d[,weight]` returns a vector and `[d,mean(weight)]` returns a value. i see why it works, but i didn't consider it.

Comment: `mean(weight)` indeed returns a value, but it doesn't mean that `weight` isn't a vector while being inserted into `mean`, but I think I see your confusion.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think I was surprised that `mean(weight)` returned the mean of each group, rather than the mean of the whole column. I wonder what's the most succinct way of subtracting each group mean by the grand mean?

Comment: perhaps `d[,mean(weight)-mean(d$weight),by=Group]` ?

Comment: If you are using the `by` argument you can't calculate the grand mean at the same time. Either create a new column with grand mean assigned to and then run the calculation by group while subtracting this column or do something like the following `temp <- mean(d$weight) ; d[,Diff: = mean(weight) - temp, by=Group]`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calculating `mean(d$weight)` in each iteration, as it isn't efficient, just create a separate variable like I did. Anyway, have a +1 for the effort :)

Comment: @Jeff, yes, `mean(d$weight)` would compute the grand mean (albeit every time, which could be avoided, as David points out). Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

With library(dplyr)

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise( avg = mean(weight)) %>%
  left_join(df1, by="Group") %>%
  mutate( diff = weight - avg)
```

Comment: this is not my answer , sorry

Comment: @user3546966 This gives your output, deosn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%   #df is your dataframe
group_by(Group)%>%
mutate(Diff=weight-mean(weight))

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: Group

  Group weight Diff
1     A     10 -2.0
2     A     14  2.0
3     B     12 -1.0
4     B     14  1.0
5     C     14  1.0
6     C     12 -1.0
7     D     12 -0.5
8     D     13  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a plain old function, this should do:

```
calcDiff <- function(data, group.col="Group", out.col="Diff") {
  lev <- levels(data[,group.col])
  avg.list = list()
  for( group in lev ) {
    avg.list[[group]] <- mean(data[data[,group.col]==group,"weight"])
  }
  avg.list <- unlist(avg.list)
  grp.averages <- avg.list[lev[data[,group.col]]]
  data[,out.col] = data[,'weight'] - grp.averages
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: Baliant-thank you. How I can use this function if I have three varaibles like Group?

Comment: I'd add parameters to the function specifying the group and output column names. I edited it to my solution. Then you can call this method 3 times with the different parameters.